# JAX-RS jersey Client: Reading the Response with status code

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I am using this code for invoking a jersey JAX-RS service using a jersey client.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
    Client client = Client.create(config);

    WebResource service = client.resource(getBaseURI());

    String msg = service.path("rest").path("ExceptionDemo").path("user").queryParam("id", "001").get(String.class);     
    System.out.println(msg);

}

private static URI getBaseURI() {
    return UriBuilder.fromUri("http://localhost:8045/ExceptionHanlding").build();
}
```

This code works fine when the Response status code is 200. But for anything other than 200, this code throws an exception.

How to modify this code so that based on the status code of the response it performs some action?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use `.get(ClientResponse.class)` instead of `.get(String.class)`. That suppresses the "exception on bad status" behavior, and the [ClientResponse](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/latest/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/client/ClientResponse.html) gives you access to details about the HTTP response. The behavior is briefly described in the user guide under ["Receiving a response"](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#d4e665).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it resolved my problem. I can see in the link they are not using this: `EntityTag e = response.getEntityTag();`. What is the use of this?

Comment: Put briefly, an entity tag uniquely or near-uniquely identifies a response body to enable better caching. Read more in the [HTTP spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.11) or on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag).

Comment: In Jersey 2 this doesn't work instead see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31360598/403999