# JAX RS Client: Catch exception message while making a REST call

Tags: java, rest, exception, jax-rs

I'm using ResteasyClient to make a REST client to my another service A. Say, service A throws an exception **CustomException** with a message : **Got Invalid request.**
Here is how I am using the Client:

```
public Response callServiceA(final String query) {
    ResteasyClient client = new ResteasyClientBuilder().build();
    String link = "abc.com/serviceA";
    ResteasyWebTarget target = client.target(link).path("call");
    Form form = new Form();
    form.param("query", query);
    Response response;
    try {
        String data =
                target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
                        .post(Entity.entity(form,
                                MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_TYPE),
                                String.class);
        response = Response.ok().entity(data).build();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        String message = e.getMessage();
        e.printStackTrace();
        response = Response.serverError().entity(e.getMessage()).build();
    } finally{
        client.close();
    }
    return response;
}
```

However, when I print the stacktrace, I'm unable to find my custom error message. I can just see the message as **HTTP 400 Bad Request**.
Could you please suggest me how to access the error message?

**NOTE:** I am able to get the error message when I call the serviceA using the restClient. Hence, I dont think there is an issue with the service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't deserialize the response straight to a `String`.

```
String data = ...
          .post(Entity.entity(form,
                MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_TYPE),
                String.class);
```

When you do this (and there is a problem), you just get a client side exception, which doesn't carry information about the response.  Instead just get the `Response` with the overloaded [`post`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/SyncInvoker.html#post-javax.ws.rs.client.Entity-) method

```
Response response = ...
          .post(Entity.entity(form,
                MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_TYPE));
```

Then you can get details from the `Response`, like the status and such. You can get the body with `response.readEntity(String.class)`. This way you don't need to handle any exceptions. Just handle conditions based on the status.

Do note though that the `Response` above is an inbound `Response`, which is different from the outbound `Response` in your current code. So just make sure not to try and send out an inbound `Response`.

Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33239032/2587435) and it's comments for some design ideas.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution. I'm able to access the error message by performing .readEntity method on the incoming response.